# How do I make this condition actually work, I am using woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Basically I am trying to create a condition where if a product is equal to a specific subcategory which is 2 other categories (specifically garden & roof) in this case.

I am trying to make it where if the product is not equal to the housing category it will print the cart addition which is a add to cart button. This does not work for some reason, and also I need help with a continuation statement (else, elseif) for if the product is actually the housing category it will just do nothing and not print that small form but actually let that sites page still function and load.

```
<div class="cart_addition_form">
<?php 
    if ($product->get_categories() != "housing") {
        $action = 'woocommerce_cart_addition_form';
} ?>
</div>
```

I tried many types of if, else loops etc with different ways of using the loops but so many of the times it would just make my site crash and not load that specific page... I am expecting it to where if it detects housing as a category that the customer opens it will not allow them to add to cart, but if it detects another two categories which could be garden or roof, it will allow the customer to see the add to cart function and use it.

Comment: `$product->get_categories()` returns an array so a simple `!-` test will not work [Useful Manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

Comment: If yo are doing development then Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

[has_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) function will be best to make check your need. However I don't understand the other part related to the action thing, but for the category exists/linked check you should use `has_term`. You need to pass the terms slugs array or single term and taxonomy name and product id.

So the code will look like this:

```php
<div class="cart_addition_form">
<?php 
if ( has_term( ['housing'], 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    $action = 'woocommerce_cart_addition_form';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This has been better than the other answers, I mean at least it does not crash my site, I think product_cat is a major factor that actually should be making it work because I do have that in another part of my files which actually allows for pulling from a list of categories.

However, I am wondering must I keep get_id() or use get_categories()?

Because it is not adding the cart function anywhere throughout all the categories after using that code that you sent.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't understand what you're doing with action and how that should be applied. from your given description and code snippets I am unable to figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: is there anyway i can message you somewhere else maybe discord because this is so hard to communicate with

Comment: I think it's better you edit your original post and explain your actions and expected results in detail and provide enough code to understand your actions. You can also record the screen and explain things easily and share the public link of the video. Hopefully, someone will understand your question will post the answers.